# Can't link Tkinter scrollbar to Listbox

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, listbox, scrollbar

I am trying to create a part manager using Tkinter and Sqlite3, but the scrollbar doesn't seem to work. It shows up on the screen, but it isn't usable and doesn't seem to be linked to the listbox.
OBS: I have to use .grid() due to organization.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Define and Grid Listbox / Scrollbar
parts_list = Listbox(root, height=12, width=86, borderwidth=3)
parts_list.grid(row=0, column=0, pady=10, padx=10)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1)

#Set Scroll to Listbox
parts_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)
scrollbar.configure(command=parts_list.yview)

#Populate Listbox
for x in range(20):
    parts_list.insert(END, 'Lorem Ipsum' + str(x))

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `sticky=NS` to the scrollbar widget, Try this:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

#Define and Grid Listbox / Scrollbar
parts_list = Listbox(root, height=12, width=86, borderwidth=3)
parts_list.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=1)

scrollbar = Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=NS)

#Set Scroll to Listbox
scrollbar.configure(command=parts_list.yview)
parts_list.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

#Populate Scrollbar
for x in range(20):
    parts_list.insert(END, 'Lorem Ipsum' + str(x))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: It Works! Thanks a lot, Thaer ! But it seems like Traversy Media has some kind of magic editor, because he didn't need that to make it work haha

Comment: @PedroSales lol Not sure why he didn't need to use it. Might be a different version of Tkinter or a different OS.

Comment: Yeah, I think he runs it on Mac. I didn't know it made a difference though.